# Javascript Promise Failure function not working

Tags: javascript

I'm using a third party Javascript API for displaying seatmaps for flights in our website.

I'm not an expert in Javascript and have some trouble understanding promises in Javascript.

So I have this function that I call to save the seats selected by user.

```
seatmap
    .save(jsondata)
    .then(
        function (result)
        {
            console.log("Save");
            SaveSeats();
        },
        function(error)
        {
            console.log("Error");
            ErrorHandling();
        });
```

Whenever the API returns a 500 Internal Server Error it doesnot go inside the error function. According to my understanding if the function results in an error it should  go to function(error).

Please let me know the best way to do this.Since I have to create live bookings to test this,I'm not supposed to test this many times.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I have edited it now..

Comment: @LintaSheelkumar what is seatmap and whats the code inside the save function?

Comment: The problem is in seatmap.save, not in the code you posted. The code you posted is fine.

Comment: @Magrangs I just call my fonction to save the seats and if it is working fine..My only problem is when I get a 500 server error from the API ,it doesnt go to function(error)

Comment: @LintaSheelkumar we need to see the code inside save of seatmap as that is where the issue will be

Comment: @Magrangs in my case when I get a 500 error it doesnt go inside seatmap.save() and from what Quentin said I understand it is that functions problem

Comment: @Magrangs Are you aware of any function that I can use like finally or completed that gets executed at the very last

Comment: @LintaSheelkumar The issue lies within the save function that is on the object seatmap. We do not know what this code does as it has not been posted here so it is impossible to determine exactly what the issue is. We need to see the code inside of the save function of seatmap. There is not an issue withe the code that has been posted here. The issue lies within the save function which we cannot see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function passed to `new Promise(function_goes_here)` gets two arguments. `resolve` and `reject`. The values of these arguments are functions.

If `reject` gets called, then the error function you pass to `then()` gets called.

It is the responsibility of the code **inside `seatmap.save`** to call `reject` (or otherwise expose the error to you) if there is a `500` error.

Comment: So in my case(500 error) it should go to function(error) right? Is there any reason why its not?

Comment: @LintaSheelkumar — "It is the responsibility of the code inside seatmap.save". If it doesn't do it, then it doesn't do it.

Comment: @LintaSheelkumar based on the AJAX library you are using, HTTP errors may or may not be rejected (I know the fetch library resolves every time reagrdless off the HTTP response code - unless there was a network error). What this answer is suggesting is that the method `setmap.save(jsondata)` must internally check the status of the response and `reject` if there was an error based on the response and the data contained in the response.

Comment: Ok..Will this work? var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

  seatmap.save(jsondata).then(function (result){
            console.log("Save");
            SaveSeats();
        },
        function(error)
        {
            console.log("Error");
            ErrorHandling();
        });

   resolve("Success");
     
                           });
                           promise.then(function (result) {

     

                           }, function (err) {
    
                               /* handles errors */
                           });

 });

Comment: @ChiragRavindra Since it is done by the third party they might take take a long tome to resolve this..Is there any workaround?

Comment: @LintaSheelkumar no, what you have shared will not work. The code INSIDE of `setmap.save(jsondata)` must do this. If you cannot touch that function, what you can do is make sure your data is as expected in your `then()` handler and manually reject using `return Promise.reject(error)` if the data you need is unavailable.

Comment: @ChiragRavindra Im unable to manually reject because the save function gets executed last and I can't put a condition after this function to reject or do anything else..Basically I need to send an email to client if this function fails,,